# Python float to int, and int to str

Tags: string, python-2.7, int, floating

```
w = 0 
while w <= 1.0:
    print str(int(w*10))
    w += 0.1
```

Why this answer is 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 9 9
where is 8 and 10?

i just use

```
print str(int(0.8*10))
```

It print '8'

Thank u! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.1` cannot be represented in binary, so there is some round off error. Let's try a different script:

```
w = 0 
while w <= 1.0:
    print repr(w)
    w += 0.1
```

What does it print?

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
```

Comment: Its worth also adding that `int` truncates towards zero, instead of rounding. Which is why `int(7.9)` is `7`, not `8`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the design of floating points.
0.1 is a fraction, that cannot be represented exactly as binary (base 2) fraction.

See for yourself, what I mean:

I removed the conversion to int and the uneccessary conversion to str:

```
w = 0
while w <= 1.0:
  print(w*10)
  w += 0.1
```

prints:

```
0
1.0
2.0
3.0000000000000004
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
7.999999999999999
9.0
9.999999999999998
```

as converting a float to int always just cuts off the part after the point,
it will print 7 and 9 twice.

See http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues for more information on this.
Especially: http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error

Comment: How did this comment add any new information that wasn't already in the previoud answer (which this is very similar too), or already stated in a comment?

Comment: I didn't notice there was an answer already, when I posted it. Anyway as for your question: it provides the links to the python documentation, which are not present in the answer above... so I'd say it provides more information.